# My Header and Footer overlaps with the content in a PDF Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pdf, css, header

I am trying to render my PDF page with a header and a footer, that are actually images, and a content, that expands in more than one page.

The problems that I am facing are:

- The Header gets rendered properly but appears as a background image, while the content starts displaying since at the beginning of the page.
- The footer, can be seen only 30 %, while the other part of the footer, doesn't get shown.
- The footer doesn't get wrapped in a dotted rectangle(*but this is a minor issue*).

  To develop this page, I've been refering to this [post](https://forcesecret.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/visualforce-page-for-pdf-and-dynamic-header-and-footer/) and I've tried to adapt it.

> 1. The CSS Style used is the following(**dynaPdf**):

```
@page {
    @top-center {
        content: element(header);
    }

    @bottom-left {
        content: element(footer);
    }
}

div.header {
    padding: 10px;
    position: running(header);
}

div.footer {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    position: running(footer);
}

.pagenumber:before {
    content: counter(page);
}

.pagecount:before {
    content: counter(pages);
}
```

> 2. The component used to visualize a header or footer is as follows(**DynaPdfComponent**):

```
<apex:component >
<apex:attribute required="true"  type="string" name="type" description="specify header and footer type" />

<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.dynaPdf}"/>

<div class="{!type}">
    <apex:componentBody />
</div>
```

> 3. The visualforce page used for the test purpose, is:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" id="pge" renderAs="pdf" controller="DynaPdfPageCTRL">

<head>
    <style>
        div.content {
            border-style:dotted;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top:10cm;
            margin-bottom:10cm;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<!-- HEADER -->
<c:dynaPdfComponent type="header" > 

  <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Header_Test_ES}" height="100%" width="100%"/>

</c:dynaPdfComponent>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<c:dynaPdfComponent type="footer">

    <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Footer_Test_ES}" width="100%" height="100%" />

</c:dynaPdfComponent>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="content">
    <apex:repeat value="{!testStringList}" var="s">                    
        <b>{!s}</b>
        <br/>
    </apex:repeat>  
</div>
```

> 4. The controller used to generate a sample list of strings (**DynaPdfPageCTRL**), is:

```
public class DynaPdfPageCTRL {
    public List<String> testStringList {
        get {
            List<String> result = new List<String>();
            for (Integer i = 1; i < 250; i++ ) {
                result.add('TEST CONTENT ' + i);
            }
            return result;
        } set;
    } 

    public DynaPdfPageCTRL() { }
}
```

Along with this post, I am attaching also:
a) The view of the rendered page: [image: ScreenShot]
b) The header image: [image]
c) The footer image: [image]

Thank you so much guys.
Greetings,
Endrit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the main issues is that you should put your margin measurements in the @page element and remove them from the content div. For readability, i've put this all in one VF page:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" id="pge" renderAs="pdf" controller="DynaPdfPageCTRL" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" >
<head>
    <style>
        @page {
            margin-top: 4cm;
            margin-bottom: 3cm;

            @top-center {
                content: element(header);
            }
            @bottom-left {
                content: element(footer);
            }
        }

        div.header {
            padding: 10px;
            position: running(header);
        }
        div.footer {
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            position: running(footer);
        }
        .pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
        }
        .pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
        }
        div.content {
            border-style:dotted;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header">
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Header_Test_ES}" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="footer">
    <div>Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/></div>
    <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Footer_Test_ES}" width="100%" height="100%" />
</div>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="content">
    <apex:repeat value="{!testStringList}" var="s">                    
        <b>{!s}</b>
        <br/>
    </apex:repeat>  
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Notice I also had to add the following attributes to the  element `applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false"`

[image]